# How can I get the time spent in Jetty queue in dropwizard project

Tags: java, performance, time, jetty, dropwizard

I am using java Dropwizard framework with the inbuilt jetty server for my application.
I can get the time spent by API methods by logging the time taken or by `@Timed` annotation.
But How can I get the time taken for my application to accept the request i.e time spent in jetty queue before processing the request ?

I want to know how much time my application is taking from the client end.

Comment: "The Connector implementations are simple, instrumented subclasses of the Jetty connector types which measure connection duration, the rate of accepted connections, connections, disconnections, and the total number of active connections." https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/jetty/

Comment: This seems helpful but I can't figure out how exactly I can use it to get the info.

Comment: which jetty version do you use?

Comment: the support for jetty >= 9 is limited, but look in your metrics... is there e.g. a prefix `io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler`or `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool`?

Comment: You can pragmatically get to the statistics in jetty using JMX, or by passing the statistics objects themselves as attributes to the ServletContext, so your app can get them (may need to massage classpath for that)

Comment: I am using jetty 9.3